# no me borra las cookies en chrome PHP

Tags: php, cookies

resulta que tengo un archivo **salir.php** que cierra las sesiones  del usuario y ademas en caso de que el usuario haya marcado la opción "recordarme" se le borran las cookies también.. pero en chrome no me borra las cookies entonces nunca sale de la pagina (hace un recorrido de **salir.php --> index.php --> main-php**) al encontrar todavía las cookies seteadas vuelve al main.php y nunca puedo cerrar la sesión, **lo raro es que si lo pruebo en el navegador Edge anda perfectamente.. a que se debe??**

> adjunto el archivo salir.php donde borro las cookies

```
    session_start();
session_destroy();
unset($_SESSION["usuario"]);
unset($_SESSION["admin"]);
unset($_SESSION["idUsuario"]);
unset($_SESION["fotoperfil"]);
unset($_SESSION["tiempo"]);
setcookie ("marca_aleatoria_usuario_dw", "", 1,'/',false,false);
setcookie("idusuario","",1,"/",false, false);
unset($_COOKIE['idusuario']);
unset($_COOKIE['marca_aleatoria_usuario_dw']);
//setcookie("idusuario", "", time() - 3600, "/");
//setcookie("marca_aleatoria_usuario_dw", "", time() - 3600, "/");
header("Location: ../index.php");
```

Comment: ¿Has probado mi respuesta? ¿podrías indicarme el contenido de `document.cookie` usando, por ejemplo, `console.log(document.cookie);` en la consola de depuración de chrome (control + mayusculas + J)? También me vendría bien saber qué aparece en la pestaña "Application / Storage / Cookies / tu URL", sobre todo los campos "Name", "Domain" y "Path".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tras investigar a fondo el problema comprobamos que al indicar una ruta en la creación ('/') la cookie se creaba sobre un dominio superior con un punto de prefijo ".", por lo que al recibir la orden de borrado de la cookie para el dominio completo Edge la borraba pero Chrome no, por no coincidir exactamente.

Hicimos las siguientes modificaciones para que todo funcionara correctamente:

**Creación de cookies**

```
setcookie(
  'marca_aleatoria_usuario_dw',
  $numero_aleatorio,
  time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 365),
  '/',
  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
);
setcookie(
  'idusuario',
  $iduser,
  time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 365),
  '/',
  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
);
```

Se crean con una duración de un año, con las opciones de configurar directorio '/' del sitio web y para el dominio que contiene el servidor.

**Borrado de cookies**

```
setcookie(
  'marca_aleatoria_usuario_dw',
  '',
  time() - 3600,
  '/',
  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
);
setcookie(
  'idusuario',
  '',
  time() - 3600,
  '/',
  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
);
```

Como ahora coinciden exactamente los datos de creación de la cookie con los del borrado, el navegador no tiene posibilidad de confundirse de cookie al borrarla o decidir no hacerlo por no coincidir algún campo.

---

**Respuesta inicial**

La variable súperglobal [`$_COOKIES`](http://php.net/reserved.variables.cookies) no crea ni destruye cookies en el navegador. Su contenido se genera durante el inicio de la ejecución del script con el contenido de las cookies enviadas al servidor por el navegador ([más información](http://php.net/language.variables.external#language.variables.external.cookies)).

Es decir, ninguna de estas dos líneas funciona:

```
/* Esto no crea una cookie llamada "nueva_cookie" */
$_COOKIE['nueva_cookie'] = 'NUEVA COOKIE';    
/* Esto no borra una cookie llamada "vieja_cookie" */
unset($_COOKIE['vieja_cookie'];
```

En su lugar debes hacer uso de la función [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/setcookie) de la siguiente forma:

```
/* Esto SÍ crea una cookie llamada "nueva_cookie" */
setcookie('nueva_cookie', 'NUEVA COOKIE');
/* Esto SÍ provoca el borrado de la cookie "vieja_cookie" */
setcookie('vieja_cookie', '', time() - 3600);
/* Sólo por cortesía y para que el resto del script tenga conocimiento
 de la nueva cookie "nueva_cookie" y del borardo de "vieja_cookie" */
$_SESSION['nueva_cookie'] = 'NUEVA COOKIE';
unset($_SESSION['vieja_cookie']);
```

El tercer parámetro indica cuándo debe caducar la cookie (por defecto dura hasta el cierre del navegador). Si le indicamos una fecha en el pasado provocará que se borre del navegador.

El la práctica el servidor genera una cabecera HTTP `Set-Cookie: vieja_cookie=deleted; ...; ; Max-Age=-3600` para crear una nueva cookie "vieja_cookie" con un valor "deleted" y, además, con una edad máxima negativa que provoca que sea inmediatamente descartada (borrada).

Para finalizar las sesiones gestionadas por PHP (presuponiendo una sesión ya iniciada con [`session_start()`](http://php.net/session_destroy)) se necesita hacer lo siguiente:

```
// Si se desea destruir la sesión completamente, borre también la cookie de sesión.
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}
/* Borramos los datos de sesión (pero no su archivo asociado) */
unset($_SESSION);
// Finalmente, destruir la sesión.
session_destroy();
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58863/discussion-on-answer-by-oscargarcia-no-me-borra-las-cookies-en-chrome-php).

Answer (score 0):

Trata haciendo que las cookies expiren sin necesidad de darle Log out.

```
setcookie("tucookie", "tuvalor", 1);
```

agregale ,1 al unset.